KeyboardAvoidingView is not working on react-native android
I searched a lot before asking this question.
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={layout.flex_1}
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : 0}
    >
      <ScrollView
        style={[layout.flex_1, gutters.paddingHorizontal_base]}
        contentContainerStyle={[layout.grow_1, layout.relative]}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
      >
        <TitleInput value={postData.title} onChangeText={(title) => updatePostData({ title })} />
        <ContentInput
          value={postData.content}
          onChangeText={handleContentChange}
          onSelectionChange={handleSelectionChange}
        />
        {images.length > 0 && <ImageCarousel images={images} onRemoveImage={handleRemoveImage} />}
        {!!pollData && <Poll />}
        <View style={[gutters.paddingBottom_small, layout.absolute, layout.bottom0, layout.left0, layout.right0]}>
          <ActionBar
            onLinkPress={handleLinkIconPress}
            onImagePress={handleImagePick}
            onPollPress={handleAddPoll}
            isImageDisabled={images.length >= MAX_IMAGES_PER_POST || !!pollData}
            isPollDisabled={!!pollData || images.length > 0}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <LinkModal
        isVisible={isLinkModalVisible}
        onClose={handleCloseLinkModal}
        onAddLink={handleAddLink}
        selectedText={getSelectedText()}
      />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

This is not working in android but working on Ios. I mean ActionBar should be at the bottom but above the keyboard always as it is in IOS. But on android nothing happening when keyboard comes up. Text does not move to the bottom neither.
React-native - ^0.73.7

What exactly doesn't work? Also, did you try using position instead of height for Android? Reference
